# Why is the concept of RKHS useful in kernel ridge regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, kernel-trick

The way I have seen kernel ridge regression introduced is as follows. Given data $(X,Y)$ you want to fit a function $f$ from a RKHS $\mathcal{H}$ to minimise some empirical loss $\sum_i L(f(x_i), y_i)$ plus a regularisation term $\lambda ||f||^2$, where $|| \cdot || $ is the norm associated with the RKHS.

It then follows from the "representer theorem" that, the minimiser of such an objective is a linear combination of $\{ k(x_i, \cdot ) \}_i$, where $k$ is the kernel associated with the RKHS, so finding the minimiser is reduced to a linear regression.

What I don't understand is what is the point of abstracting to the concept of RKHSs? It seems hard to know what the functions in the RKHS actually "look like", and what effect exactly penalising the norm has. It seems much easier to understand what one is actually doing if you start with the "representer theorem" form, since functions $k(x_i, \cdot)$ can be visualised as bump functions etc.